# cron実行について

Tags: macos, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cron

今度cronを使って、Selenium WebDriverを定時実行したいと考えていますが、以下の状況でcron実行できるのか教えていただきたいです。

状況
cronで深夜に実行コマンドを流すように記載予定。
PC(mac)は一定時間でスクリーンロックがかかります。

疑問点
1. cronはスクリーンロックがかかっている状態でも実行されるのか。
(自分なりに調べるとスリープ状態では動かないとの記載はいくつか発見できたのですが、スクリーンロックで出来るかどうかの記載は見つけることが出来ませんでした)
2. WebDriverはスクリーンロックがかかっていてもwebテストすることが可能なのか。

疑問点片方だけの回答でも結構ですので、教えてください。
宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

1. 可能です。
2. WebDriverの仕様上は可能なはずですが、ブラウザーごとの実装に大きく左右されそうなのでターゲットブラウザーで一度試してみてください。

個人的には、cronよりも、実行時のデスクトップセッションの有無等 細かい前提条件を設定により保証できる何らかのタスクスケジューラー（Jenkinsなど）を利用する方がおすすめです。